# Probability - Hausdorff distance

Tags: probability

On a 4x4 table 2 coins with radius 1 are thrown.They may overlap partially or completely but remain completely on the table.What is the probability that Hausdorff distance between the two nickels to be less than 1/2?

1)I thought that both centers of the coins should be in the red square. (not only the edges)

2)Plus the center of the second coin should be less than 1/2 from center of the first coin. (that's my interpretation of Hausdorff distance, i am not sure if it's correct)[image: 4 by 4 table with two coins]

3)The green line is less than 1/2.

4)I noticed this:[image]
but its not clear.It says "of the distance" and i can't figure out what distance!(the distance that i want e.g 1/2 or any distance)

5)Then i used this:
[image]

but I am not sure if this is the "EXPECTATION" or the "DENSITY".

6)I calculated for a=2 and b=2 and resulted that E=1.04 (double than the unit square)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you thought out the possible values for the positions of the coin centers, and how that relates to their distance?

Comment: OK, here's a hint+ - take a look at [this paper](http://www.math.kth.se/~johanph/habc.pdf) - you can get the information you need to get the distribution of distances which you can then use to get the desired probability. Comment if you get stuck (the thinking you outlined in the OP update seems spot-on, and if you get something close to 1/6 (I won't ruin it with exact answer), you're there).

Comment: I got stucked.!

Comment: You're getting close - if you fiddle with the 2-d form in the paper, and take the part of the piecewise function for your case (distance <1/2), you'll find it simplifies to $\frac{x^3}{8}-x^2+\frac{\pi  x}{2}$ (or some equivalent, depending on how you go about it). That is the *density*. Then just integrate that over desired range of distances, voilà!

Comment: Sorry for being so annoying but I really want to understand.PLZ check the last edit.

Comment: HammyTheGreek, desired ranged of distances for the integral is (0--a^2+b^2) or (0--sqrt<a^2+b^2>)? In my case (0--8) or (0--2*sqrt(2))?

Comment: I'll take a look at your work and I'll try to respond within next day - get some more points so you can chat! (this kind of interaction is better served there).

Comment: 1.I integrated the function you gave me (4th comment):< over (0--8) is 0.74071> and <over (0 --2*sqrt(2)) is 7.5988>.Both not even close to 1/6 (which you said is the aproximation of correct answer).

Comment: Ah - I am *really* sorry, I completely spaced on getting back to you on this as promised. So you got it!

Comment: Not really!That "E" is the probability of geting a distance smaller than 1/2 or I have to do one more thing?Becuase i dont get 1/6!

Comment: And if you can explain me how you obtained <(x^3)/8-x^2+(PI*x)/2> would be wonderful.I think you worked over the definition of g(s), but which one, because as I see it you have to work over first (0<s<=a^2 ; 0<1/4<=4), right?

Comment: Out and on mobile, will detail when back, but you only need to integrate over desired distance range - 0 to 1/2...

Comment: I see.Looking forward for more explanation!Now I get 1/6, but please explain me(when you get back).Thx!

Comment: OK, so, look at the piecewise function in the paper. It is clear, since we're interested effectively in a 2x2 box (where the coin centers can lie) only the first part is needed. Perhaps you missed that that is for the *square* of the distance? Doing the prescribed manipulations to get it into distance form gets you to the $\frac{x^3}{8}-x^2+\frac{\pi  x}{2}$, which is the *density*, so integrate it from 0 to 1/2 (the desired range of allowed center-center distances).

Comment: Thank you very much!You helped me a lot, HammyTheGreek!